# Minimum Android version on kid's device required for parents to set per-app application time?

Tags: applications, android-versions, parental-control

With parents running Android 13, what is the minimum Android version needed to be installed on a kid's device for parents to set per-app application time for their kids?

I need to purchase a second-hand phone for my kid and would like to make the right choice.

Note: I am not interested in using third-party parental control apps - just stock Android with Google Family Link.

**EDIT: I am specifically interested in *per-app* time limits, *not* general device-level time limits provided by all Android versions since 7.x (as well as some 5.x/6.x devices)**.

Comment: To the anonymous editor/OP: please join the site (create an account) to regain ownership of your question. Then you can edit your own question without needing approval, and also comment on the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer below was before the question was edited. Retained to help someone searching for device level compatibility.

---

[Google Family Link FAQ](https://families.google/familylink/faq/) has your answer.

> Can children or teens be supervised by Family Link on Android devices?
>
> > For **best results**, we recommend that children or teens being supervised with Family Link are using **Android devices running version 7.0 (Nougat) or higher**. Devices running Android versions 5.0 and 6.0 (Lollipop and Marshmallow) may also be able to have Family Link settings applied to them. To find out more, see our [Help Center](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7158477)

(Emphasis supplied)